# How to Dimension

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using the following code to calculate the number of text files in a folder:

```
    Dim MekdamFiles As String() = Directory.GetFiles(MekdamFolder, "*.txt")
    Dim MekdamTextFiles = CStr(MekdamFiles.Count)
```

The problem is that when the number of text files in the folder is more than 10, then obviously this doesn't work. I tried the following code, but it will give error for number of text files:

```
        Dim MekdamTextFiles(250)
        MekdamTextFiles = CStr(MekdamFiles.Count)
```

Any help to solve this is appreciated.

Comment: you should add `Option Strict On` to your project.  `Dim MekdamTextFiles = CStr(MekdamFiles.Count)` makes no sense. MekdamFiles.Count is a number, why are your converting it to a string?  Additionally, arrays always start at (0), so the proper count is determined by `Count - 1`.  What is `MekdamTextFiles` supposed to track, the count of Text files?

Comment: Thanks Plitonix for commenting; I found the above code in some VB>NET website, but it did not work for me; I changed it with this code and it worked (        Dim MekdamTextFiles As Integer = IO.Directory.GetFiles(MekdamFolder, "*.txt").Length), thanks again.

Comment: I'd stay away from that website - that was awful code. DO use Option Strict always though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    The code below worked for the purpose above:
```

> ```
>     Dim MekdamTextFiles As Integer = IO.Directory.GetFiles(MekdamFolder, "*.txt").Length
> ```

Thanks all for help and comments.